# Loading Data to bootstrap modal using JSF and Ajax

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I am looking for a working example on loading data to a modal when user click on a data table row.

I have a data table loaded with few column, when user click on a row, I wanted to open a modal loaded with selected row data.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use primefaces `DataTable - Selection (Select Events)` and add `p:ajax` with `event="rowSelect"` to update & display the primefaces `model dialog`.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do this with plan JSF, Boostrap madal & Ajax?

Comment: Bootstrap is the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework, try http://www.bootsfaces.net/, it is Bootstrap 3 and jQuery UI based JSF framework. you can Integrate bootsfaces with PrimeFaces http://www.bootsfaces.net/integration/PrimeFaces.jsf